# Display view input field based on condition angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
[{id: "1", name: "first_name"},
{id: "2", name: "last_name"},
{id: "3", name: "city"}]

<div ng-if="first_name"> <input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="user.first_name"></div>
<div ng-if="last_name"><input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="user.last_name"></div>
<div ng-if="city"><input type="text" name="city" ng-model="user.city"></div>

$scope.flag = false;
angular.forEach(response, function(value, key){
              $scope.valueName = value.name;
        if($scope.valueName == 'first_name') {
            $scope.flag = true;
        }else if($scope.valueName == 'last_name'){
            $scope.flag = true;
        }else if($scope.valueName == 'city'){
            $scope.flag = true;
        }else{
            $scope.flag = false;
        }   
          });
```

How to display view input field based on condition angularjs,

This should not be right solution because have to write too much code on it we should have to use something else that can help to read the view format and display based on condition, any assistance on it would be very greatful thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions you can loop on your JSONobject include your condition in the ng-if directly as :

```
<div ng-if="x.name == 'first_name'" ng-repeat="x in records" ng-repeat-start> <input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="user.first_name"></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'last_name'"><input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="user.last_name"></div>
<div ng-if="x.name == 'city'" ng-repeat-end><input type="text" name="city" ng-model="user.city" ></div>
```

or

without ng-repeat-start

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records">
   <div ng-if="x.name == 'first_name'" > <input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="user.first_name"></div>
    <div ng-if="x.name == 'last_name'"><input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="user.last_name"></div>
    <div ng-if="x.name == 'city'"><input type="text" name="city" ng-model="user.city" ></div>
</div>
```

So you dont need the flag anymore. The records object is your JSON object holding your field info

Comment: I think Using Ng-repeat-start and Ng-repeat-end in AngularJS. Till Angular 1.2, ng-repeat was designed to work on a single DOM element. Try after removing ng-repeat-start

Comment: added another example 2